# How to use Microsoft.AspNet.OData and Microsoft.OData.Client in the same project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nuget, odata

I would like to use the NuGet packages for [Microsoft.AspNet.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/) and [Microsoft.OData.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/) in the same C# project. An example would be an ODATA server that connects to other ODATA servers.

However, when I try to mix the two packages I get an error from NuGet saying it could not resolve dependencies.

It looks like the problem is that at the time of this writing

- `Microsoft.AspNet.OData (6.0.0)` requires `Microsoft.OData.Core (>= 7.0.0 && < 8.0.0)`

while

- `Microsoft.OData.Client (6.15.0)` requires `Microsoft.OData.Core (= 6.15.0)`.

NuGet obviously fails to find a Microsoft.OData.Core package that satisfies both conditions.

Do we have a new version of OData.Client in the horizon that will use Core>=7 and match the one used by the AspNet package?

Any other solutions in the meantime?

*I suppose one option would be to use older versions of both packages where the common dependencies are the same (5.9.1 and 6.14.0 seem to match), but I don't want to sacrifice the bug fixes and improvements that are available in the new versions, particularly from the AspNet package, since I already depend on them.*